# Connecting to Windows localhost (IIS) from another computer (another Network)

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 7 PC running IIS7.5 for its localhost. On this machine, I can successfully navigate to: localhost and ip-adress.

However, I cannot access this localhost website from another computer on other network

need Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/137054/accessing-localhost-on-iis7-from-another-computer-on-the-network

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is only accessible from this very host, hence it's name. If you try to access it from another - you will be accessing this other one (client), not the one you intended.

Answer (score -1):

Check Firewall. I guess you need to open 80 or 8080 port.
And use IP instead of localhost on another machine.